# Measure and Probability

Tags: probability, measure-theory, math-history

Can someone tell me that how did the idea to relate measure and probability come?(What's the conceptual history of measure and probability?)

Answer (score 4):

The idea is fairly natural and was codified in definitive form by Kolmogorv in his *Grundbegriffe der Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung* in 1933. There was some previous work in the area. You might want to take a look at the paper [The origins and legacy of Kolmogorov's *Grundbegriffe*](http://www.probabilityandfinance.com/articles/04.pdf) by Shafer and Vovk, especiall the third section called *Measure-theoretic probability before the Grundbegriffe*.